# How to configure multiple database sources in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to configure 2 database instances for a certain environment (say staging or production). The default rails new application just provides a single database instance how do I configure 2 database instances.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use a different database for storing certain information? Or that you want to store all your data in two different databases? The former can be accomplished by adding more configurations to `config/database.yml` and using `establish_connection` in the class files (see http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/). The latter... I'm not actually sure how that would work.

Comment: I am trying to pull data from 2 different database instances, for different portions of the UI. There won't be any relationship between the 2 databases though.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy and past one of your existing configurations such as development. and rename it as you want so, in the database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: 
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost


new_database:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: 
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

Then in the models you create for this new connection add the following methods to the model, for example:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "document"   # this allows you to hide a non comforming table name behind the rails model it is NOT necessary for establish_connection to work
  self.establish_connection "new_database"  # notice there is no = when setting this value, strange, I know.
end
```